# Same list of entries coming railscasts tokeninput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-tokeninput, jquery-rails

I am using railscasts tokeninput plugin for automcomplete. I want that only those entries shown in dropdown list which are not included in input field

My JS code is

```
$(function() {
  $("#category").tokenInput("/products/product_categories.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $("#category").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```

My controller is

```
def product_categories
category = Category.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => category.map(&:attributes) }
end
```

end

It works fine but the issue is same list appear each time. Lets suppose in dropdwon list there are two entries asia and africa. After adding asia to input field, again when click on field both asia and africa appear.

I want that if entry is already included in input field it must not appear in drop-down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JQuery tokeinput you have 2 options to prevent duplicates

1. Use `preventDuplicates` options so that even if user select same options multiple times from list it will be added only once.
2. Use callback `onResult` to manipulate response data. Read content of input field and remove those items from data array. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677002/jquery-tokeninput-tokens-are-not-getting-added) stack overflow question to see how to write `onResult` callback.

Full documentation for JQuery tokeninput is [here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).

Comment: Cna you share some information how to use preventDuplicates?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699683/problems-with-the-jquery-plugin-tokeninput